# What does "vc14_vc15" mean in opencv-4.6.0-vc14_vc15.exe?

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, msvc14

I'm trying to download a windows pre-built binary of Opencv, and from https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.6.0/ I see a file named `opencv-4.6.0-vc14_vc15.exe`.

What does `vc14_vc15` mean here? vc14 I guess it's VS2015, then vc15 is VS2017, but what's the point to list vs versions as to opencv binaries?

If the binary is compiler version specific, why not separate it into `vc14` and `vc15`? Are they compatible? if it's compatible, why not just say `vc15`?

Can I use vs 2019/2022 to create a project and link to this version?

Can I use gcc (on windows of course) to compile a project and link to this version?

I'm really confused.

Thanks.

Comment: It is version 14 and version 15.

Comment: Gee it would have been nice if somebody had actually answered this properly. I have all the same questions.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why they provide vc14 and vc15, but you can use them with recent version of visual studio. See [the official compatibility doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170)

To sum up what is said in the documentation:

- ABI compatibility is respected since visual studio 2015
- You need to use the linker used by the most recent binary you use

And I highly doubt you can use them with gcc on windows